# how to save radio btn state on playframework validation

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

We have the following radio buttons which pass the selected one to the parameter "type" in our method

```
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="a">
        Selection 1
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="b">
        Selection 2
    <input type="radio" name="type" value="c">
        Selection 3
```

What I don't have is that if a different field validation fails(so no login was entered), then this is the only widget that is cleared....all my other fields correctly persist the data since they have a value="${paramName}"

How can one get radio buttons to work this way as well?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: perhaps I did not get your question - are you trying to avoid persisting any data if neither one of these radio buttons are not checked

Comment: if validataion fails, I naturally don't want to persist data....I figured it out and will post an answer though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use formfield instead of playframeworks 'field' tag as mine has bug fixes

basically, this is what I came up with(not the prettiest but it works)...

```
#{formfield 'type'}
<input type="radio" name="type" value="a" #{if field.value=='a'}checked="checked"#{/if}>
    Selection 1
<input type="radio" name="type" value="b" #{if field.value=='b'}checked="checked"#{/if}>
    Selection 2
<input type="radio" name="type" value="c" #{if field.value=='c'}checked="checked"#{/if}>
    Selection 3
#{/formfield}
```